# Moving CALayer to another view or changing CALayer.contents, which is more efficient?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, calayer

I have many UIImage instances. I will be moving them between views in a TableView situation. I have two options:

1. Have one CALayer per UIImage, move the CALayer to different views like so: `view.layer.addSublayer(imgLayer)`
2. Have one CALayer per view, and replace the layer's contents with the UIImage as in `viewLayer.contents = uiImage`

Which of these two actions will be faster to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** This is my personal opinion.

---

**ANSWER:** *Method 1.* - `view.layer.addSublayer(imgLayer)`

**ARGUMENTS:** I believe that using the **first method** is more efficient and faster, because it doesn't need to ***"split the image"*** in `components`, and adding a `sublayer` to a `view` is more simpler.

Let me know what you think!